# How to filter with multiple fields and values in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I've been reading through the docs and been trying to achieve a solution to filter results through multiple fields and columns, however I keep getting errors; *malformed query*.

I want to filter the result with exact equal values, such as the following:

```
is_active: true
category_id: [1,2,3,4]
brand: "addidas"
gender: "male"
```

To make it more clear what I intend to do, this is how I'd like it to run if it would be written in SQL:

```
SELECT .... WHERE 
is_active= 1 AND category_id IN(1,2,3,4) 
AND brand='addidas' AND gender='male'
```

My query in DSL goes as following:

```
{
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "terms": {
                                "category_id": [
                                    1,
                                    2,
                                    3
                                ]
                            },
                            "term": {
                                "is_active": true
                            },
                            "term": {
                                "brand": "addidas"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I filter multiple fileds and values as described, in elasticsearch?**

*If you need extra information from me that is required to answer the question, leave a comment.* If you add a link to the docs, please also provide an example (with query dsl) of how my current, or similar situations should be solved.

Comment: Please show the full error you're getting and a sample document that you need to be matched. Also I think the solution is probably to simply remove the `nested` query.

Comment: @Kilise, plz add sample of document that indexed in elasticsearch

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the following code:

The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will contribute to the score.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must" : [
            {"term" : { "is_active" : true}},
            {"term" : { "gender" : "female"}},
            {"term" : { "brand" : "addidas"}},
            {"terms": { "categoryId": [1,2,3,4]}}
        ]
    }
}
```

Queries specified under the filter element have no effect on scoring

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter" : [
            {"term" : { "is_active" : true}},
            {"term" : { "gender" : "female"}},
            {"term" : { "brand" : "addidas"}},
            {"terms": { "categoryId": [1,2,3,4]}}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. It was really hard to figure out the position of the objects, even when reading the docs. Merci!

Comment: This doesn't work at all. This only does a filter on the last item "categoryId", all others: "is_active", "gender", and "brand" are ignored. Why? Because they're under the same object, and JSON.. and every other language I know off, can only have a single key, and you have "must" 4 times under "bool".

Comment: `must` is an array of conditions, you pass each instance as an object.

Comment: @Dalibor Karlović: Very thanks for the comment, I edit the answer

Comment: @Javier Buzzi: Very thanks for the comment, I edit the answer

Comment: This is not a filter, it should affect the ranking,

Comment: @Radio Controlled- Thanx for your attention, I add the filter part to the answer