# Not getting output when using terms to filter on multiple values

Tags: python, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I have a table in opensearch in which the format of every field is "text".

This is how my table looks like

[image]

Now the **query(q1)** which I am running in opensearch looks like this. i am not getting any output. But when I run **query q2** then I get the output.

```
q1 = {"size":10,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"multi_match":{"query":"cen","fields":["name","alias"],"fuzziness":"AUTO"}}],"filter":[{"match_phrase":{"category":"Specialty"}},{"match_phrase":{"prov_type":"A"}},{"match_phrase":{"prov_type":"C"}}]}}}

q2 = {"size":10,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"multi_match":{"query":"cen","fields":["name","alias"],"fuzziness":"AUTO"}}],"filter":[{"match_phrase":{"category":"Specialty"}},{"match_phrase":{"prov_type":"A"}}]}}}
```

Now I want to apply multiple filtering on prov_type. I have tried using terms also with prov_type in list like ['A','B'].

Can anyone please answer this on how to apply **multiple filters** on value for single column in opensearch/elasticsearch. **Datatype for every field is text**.
Have already tried this - [How to filter with multiple fields and values in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614104/how-to-filter-with-multiple-fields-and-values-in-elasticsearc)

Mapping for the index

```
GET index/_mapping

{
  "spec_proc_comb_exp" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "alias" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "category" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "prov_type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "specialty_code" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know in case you need anymore information

Comment: Can you share `GET <index_name>/_mapping`

Comment: @MusabDogan Done. Please have a look

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is the below answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `should` query to filter your data with the `OR` condition.

**[Should: The clause (query) should appear in the matching document.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)**

```
GET test_allergy/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "prov_type": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "prov_type": "C"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Note: [**You can set minimum_should_match as a number or percentage.**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html)